# Is it possible to create a file somewhere in github via browser?

Tags: browser, github

I know you can edit a file in githubs website, but I can't find if you can create or delete a file.

---

Note that since early December 2012, you can create **[new files directly from GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1327-creating-files-on-github)**:

[image: Create new File]

> **ProTip™**: You can pre-fill the filename field using just the URL.
>   Typing `?filename=yournewfile.txt` at the end of the URL will pre-fill the filename field with the name `yournewfile.txt`.

[image: d]

Comment: I'd just like to say I hope this closed question gets locked to prevent deletion or reopened, as it seems to be within the scope of the FAQ and is really useful.

Comment: Nice pro-tip. Is it even possible to pre-fill the content of the page? I know it is possible when creating issues for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can login to [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) and clone the repository and then create/delete as you like and then make a git push.

Comment: The original question asks how to create a file "in githubs website". That makes other git-aware tools/websites off-topic. Even if they are able to connect to an existing github repository.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is not possible yet, sorry.

If you have good reasons, you can send a Feature Request here:
http://support.github.com/discussion/new