# Upload a code file to GitHub in browser

Tags: file-upload, github

I dont want to install github's client, i know you can edit code files online, but can you upload / create them?

Thank you for any replies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a file somewhere in github via browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147635/is-it-possible-to-create-a-file-somewhere-in-github-via-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log in with your GitHub account to [Prose.io](http://prose.io/), which - at minimum - allows direct editing of existing code and documents, as well as creating new code files. It can't initialize new repositories (not yet, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you can't.

Longer answer: You don't need the github client to upload stuff to github, just git :)